# read_excel or read_csv on pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I tried the pandas method but it doesn't work. The name of my file is 'Classeur1'. I can't load it on Jupyter or Spyder.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("TP 2 FIN 3500.xlsx")

df.head()
```

I get:

```
  File "<ipython-input-1-2b6f31d9e40c>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/alber/.spyder-py3/temp.py', wdir='C:/Users/alber/.spyder-py3')

  File "C:\Users\alber\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 827, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Users\alber\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 110, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Users/alber/.spyder-py3/temp.py", line 2, in <module>
    df = pd.read_csv("TP 2 FIN 3500.xlsx")

  File "C:\Users\alber\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 685, in parser_f
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)

  File "C:\Users\alber\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 457, in _read
    parser = TextFileReader(fp_or_buf, **kwds)

  File "C:\Users\alber\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 895, in __init__
    self._make_engine(self.engine)

  File "C:\Users\alber\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 1135, in _make_engine
    self._engine = CParserWrapper(self.f, **self.options)

  File "C:\Users\alber\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 1917, in __init__
    self._reader = parsers.TextReader(src, **kwds)

  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 382, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.__cinit__

  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 689, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._setup_parser_source

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] File b'TP 2 FIN 3500.xlsx' does not exist: b'TP 2 FIN 3500.xlsx'

I also tried both method with the absolute: C:\Users\alber\Documents\Downloads\python stockage
```

Unable to load file using pandas dataframe

Thanks !

Comment: Have you tried using `pandas.read_excel` from [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html), also instead of using `df = pd.read_excel("TP 2 FIN 3500.xlsx")`, try using an `os.pathlike` object using the `os` module eg: `import os; pathname = os.path.join(filename)` and then `df = pd.read_excel(pathname)`

Comment: also install xlrd. I don't know why pandas does not install it already.

Answer (score 0):

For reading excel try this.

```
df = pd.read_excel("TP 2 FIN 3500.xlsx")
```

If Classeur1 is CSV file then try this.

```
df = pd.read_excel("Classeur1.csv")
```

Also, check if the file is placed in the same directory as the notebook, for it to be found.

Answer (score 0):

You read excel files as follows:

```
df = pd.read_excel (r'Path where the Excel file is stored\File name.xlsx')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using pd.read_csv() then convert your excel file to .CSV formate. Aslo put your excel or .csv file in this directory: C:\Users\alber.

```
df= pd.read_csv("your_filename.csv")
```

You can also use one more method  by changing your jupyter running directory path by using below code:-

```
os.chdir('D:\folder_path_of_csv_file')
print(os.getcwd())
df= pd.read_csv("your_filename.csv")
```